# JQuery link ON binding doesn't work in Yii GridView Pagination

Tags: php, jquery, gridview, yii, binding

I bind dynamic icon links from CGridView (class `icon-link` , [image]) with simple jQuery `on` script; demo is [here](http://tarex.ru/assortment/index/3859). Script:

```
<div id="info-popup"></div>  

<?php $ajaxUrl = $this->createUrl('itemInfo');
      Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('info-popup-script', "
       jQuery('.info-link').on('click', function(){ jQuery.ajax({'data':{id: this.id   
        },'url':'{$ajaxUrl}','cache':false,'success':function(html){jQuery('#info-popup').html(html)}});return false;});
      ", CClientScript::POS_END);
```

It works well for the 1st page, but after moving to other pages (2,3...) the functionality doesn't work, though the js code is present there:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

   jQuery('.info-link').on('click', function(){ jQuery.ajax({'data':{id: this.id },'url':'/app3/assortment/itemInfo','cache':false,'success':function(html){jQuery('#info-popup').html(html)}});return false;});
   ...
</script>
```

Particulary *no ajax call is fired*. What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to bind it by its parent or document element like,

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('info-popup-script', "
   jQuery(document).on('click','.info-link', function(){.....
   .....
", CClientScript::POS_END);
```

Comment: thank you, it works. But could you explain (or some docs) why the second way is better than the 1st approach that i tried originally?

Comment: http://www.go4expert.com/articles/bind-jquery-events-dynamically-created-t29931/ and a better https://www.google.co.in/?#q=dynamic+binding+using+on+jquery